# Jquery Mobile: Alterar cor de fundo da página

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Como eu posso sobrepor a estilização desse arquivo *css* para alterar a cor de fundo da pagina?
Já tentei utilizar o `!important` no *background* do *body* e mesmo assim não adianta.

Eu sei que é esse arquivo que está fazendo isso, pois se eu o remover, tudo funciona normalmente.

Link do arquivo: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css

PS: Parar de utilizar esse arquivo não é uma opção.

Comment: Consegue fazer um [mcve] demonstrando esse comportamento?

Comment: Tente na força bruta, inclua direto na tag `<body style="background: #000;">`

Comment: Tambem não funciona.

Comment: Tente esta resposta no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470510/1377664

Comment: Funcionou! Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Que bom! Posta vc mesmo uma resposta pra ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 2):

O seguinte código substitui a estilização:

```
.ui-page {
    background: red;
}
```